# Quiver plot in X-Z plane instead of X-Y plane

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

In MATLAB, `quiver` will plot a vector field on the x-y plane by default. Is there a way to rotate the image so that is lies on the x-z plane?

I have tried creating a 3D matrix and using commands like `streamslice` and `quiver3`. However I have a large number of data points that are irregularly spaced so this results in some inaccurate interpolation and matrices that are too big.

It seems the easiest option would be to use a command like `rotate`, but that doesn't seem to work with `quiver`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use `quiver3` and add zero-valued (or whatever constant `y` you want) inputs in the dimensions that you don't care about

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:0.2:2,0:0.2:2);
u = cos(x).*y;
v = sin(x).*y;

Q = quiver3(x, zeros(size(x)), y, u, zeros(size(u)), v);

axis equal
```

[image]